# django - use cloudinary only for image manipulation and save the image to local project folder?

Tags: python, django, cloudinary

is there an option to do some image cropping in cloudinary and save it in local project folder. transformations like detect face and save as profile image. is there any other plugins for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out official [cloudinary documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_integration) regarding django integration.

Also there is python library on which this is based upon ( [pycloudinary](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary))

Comment: this allows to be saved on the cloud only, not to local folder. Note i am on offline development.

Answer (score 0):

All images (originals and derived) are saved in your Cloudinary cloud storage.
If you want to tell the browser to download a specific image instead of showing it, you can use the `attachment` flag (`fl_attachment` in URLs).
For example, resizing the image to a width of 300 (`w_300` in URLs) before downloading it - 
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_300/fl_attachment/sample.jpg